# C# Windows service convert XLSX to CSV

Tags: c#, .net, excel, windows, service

I am trying to write a windows service in C# .net framework, the service should open a given excel file which contains calculations and formulas, refresh the contents (calculations depend on current time), and write to a csv or a new xlsx file only the values (not the formulas within the cells), this would be the equivalent of PasteSpecial in excel. When i run my code as a console app it works, however when i have it running as a service (Log on as Administrator), i get #NAME? in all the rows in the new csv, as if the formula or calculation is failing.
What am i missing here, and as a side general question, can a windows service open excel files read them and then create new ones, if so which libraries can i use to achieve this ?

Here is the code im using:

```
 string excelFilePath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\Test.xlsx";

            try
            {
                using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFilePath)))
                {
                    Manager.LogDebugMessage("Excel file opened successfully.");


                    using (StreamWriter csvWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Test\Test.csv"))
                    {
                        foreach (var worksheet in excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells.Calculate();
                            worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

                            Manager.LogDebugMessage($"Contents of Worksheet: {worksheet.Name}");

                            for (int row = 1; row <= worksheet.Dimension.Rows; row++)
                            {
                                csvWriter.WriteLine(string.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(1, worksheet.Dimension.Columns)
                                    .Select(col => $"{worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value}")));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    Manager.LogDebugMessage("Excel data refreshed successfully.");



                    Manager.LogDebugMessage("Excel file converted to PDF successfully.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Manager.LogDebugMessage($"Error: {ex.Message} | {ex.InnerException?.Message}");
            }
```